# new server from Godaddy runny really slow

Tags: apache, apache2

I purchased a new dedicated server from Godaddy yesterday. The website pages are loading really slow. I have 16 GB of Ram and i7 processor. I am trying to optimize my Apache server for high traffic 10K+ active users. Here is the old and new settings:

```
OLD:
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>


New:
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients         2500
    ServerLimit        2500
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
    KeepAlive On
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
    KeepAliveTimeout 3
    Timeout 30
</IfModule>
```

What are the best setting to solve my problem. Note the website is based php mysqli application. Also it has about 3 to 5 images on each page.

Comment: Define "slow". Which part is loading slow, what kinds of loading times are you seeing? Have you benchmarked the code to see what in it might be causing the problem? In its current form, this is much too broad to get a useful response.

Comment: when I click a link to my website, its taking a while to connect and start displaying the website. from 7 to 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](http://linuxstuffs.wordpress.com/apache-optimization/) - I use it all the time as a reference.

I also strongly recommend having a play with apache's benchmark tool once you've got it up and running. Keep an eye for a few days on the traffic intake and adjust settings accordingly. Every setup is different - the applications you run can use variable amounts of memory. Maybe the most commonly used page is a low resource page? Maybe people spend a lot of time on single pages? It's all conditional.

Good luck!

Comment: I can say %95 of the users will be on one page. but I pass a get var to change the content of that page.